# Titanium or Javascript: Get value of property above in the same object creation curly braces

Tags: javascript, class, properties, titanium, inheritance

I want to be able have the idlength property take on the property of the id.

```
var aclass = {id:1234, idlength:this.id*2,};
alert (aclass.idlength);
```

But I am getting the error that id is not defined. What is wrong?
Will idlength:this.id*2 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using object literal notation to create an object the values you are assigning can not refer to other properties in the same object - the object doesn't exist until after the whole literal is evaluated.

You can do it like this:

```
var aclass = {id:1234};
aclass.idlength = aclass.id * 2;

alert (aclass.idlength);
```

Where basically you use an object literal to create any properties that don't depend on other properties, then assign the other properties individually.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
var idVal = 1234,
    aclass = {
       id : idVal,
       idlength : idVal * 2
    };
```

There's no problem assigning properties equal to other variables that are already defined.

Also, I wouldn't leave a trailing comma after the last property because some browsers don't like it. (And I agree with them.)

Comment: Why is the trailing comma a bad thing?

Comment: As I said, some browsers don't like it - that is, they consider it an error so the code won't run. You may think it doesn't matter if you're not targeting those browsers, but if you get in the habit of not leaving trailing commas then you never have to worry.